# Fixing key processing conflict between custom controls, in case of more than one control on a form?

Tags: c#

I made a custom text editor control, which processes the arrow key. The problem is when there is more than one control in a form, the arrow key processing is queued: at the first time the event is processed with focused control, next time with another custom control, then again focused control and so on. So what should I do to process the arrow key with just the custom text editor control, not with all controls on a form?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I just want to fix the unusual behavior of an arrow key processing. I think that the arrow key should be processing with just focused custom control, not with all the custom controls in a form by rotation.

Comment: no sweat, just pointing out the problems with your question

Comment: thanks for your remark, how make sweat?

Comment: It's an expression :) "no sweat" means "don't worry"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem actually was because of WinForm navigation with arrows keys. So i disable the navigation for my text editor. For that OnPreviewKeyDown event was overrided like in the example:

```
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Right:
                e.IsInputKey = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling with a KeyEventArgs object. Any control that consumes the key event should set the KeyEventArgs.Handled property to true to indicate that they have done so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help me.